# "Верстальщик с опытом" Кто поможет в получении ответа на критику?

Tags: html, css, css-animation, адаптивная-верстка

День добрый!

[Есть задача](https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Ji3iOAwZ56A_Og) (видео) - *работодателя*.

Есть [репозиторий с версткой](https://github.com/Tryd0g0lik/test_hhr.git) (с анимацией) - *в ответ работодателю*.

Есть сопроводительное письмо (от меня) в котором говориться, что работа сделана не до конца (Конечный desktop, JS - не прописаны) , просто есть нюансы для уточнения - вот и отправил работодателю.

> 1. При работе конструктором не пользовался. Весь код руками.
> 2. Не смотря на то, что верстка сделана не для всех устройств - посмотреть можно от ширины в 320 и выше.
>
> 2.1. Ширина в `320 рх` сделана с учетом "Пиксельной верстки". Скриншот в репозитории  Mobile_320.png
>
> 3. Меню Бургер сделано в мобильной версии, просто скрыто. На бургер даже анимацию повесил. Осталось его повесить на JS для появления.
> 4. Осталось Desktop и JS прописать

Ответ работодателя

> Посмотрел я и наш программист ваше задание. Выполнили не плохо, но
> есть ряд недочетов, которые проявляются в ввиду отсутствия опыта
> работы с коммерческими проектами

Ребята, очень нужна критика, чтоб понять и работать с ней. **Чем моя верстка отличается от коммерческой?**

---

10 лет на фрилансе. Работаю один спросить больше негде.

Бургер в мобильной версии сверстан. Просто скрыт "`display: none`"

Comment: Ну как минимум писать все стили в одном файле.. Как-то не очень, как для разработки, особенно в маштабном проекте. В большинстве стилей, вы .. (не помню как называется) используете аля `selector selector`, после чего такие стили сложно будет перебить. Вы же используете "BEM", а там все же каждый элемент независимый. Да и использовать jQ? Зачем?

Comment: 1. по возможности не используйте ```id``` . 2. если используется препроцессор - разбейте блоки на отдельные файлы 3. используйте svg sprite 4. бэм - у вас не совсем правильно используется эта методология. 5. используйте какой нибудь сборщик (Rollup, Parcel). 6. зачем подключается пустой js файл?

Comment: @Oliver Patterson , Вы про селекторы в верстке css? Спасибо. Хоть вроде и стараюсь их использовать внутри объекта.  
На каждый элемент `class ` или `id`  расставить?
.
JQ, не совсем понял. Писать ручками весь функционал?  Так на эти JQю Bootstrap спрос у работодателей. Не совсем замечание с JQ понял

Comment: @soledar10
1. Id - ok/
2. препроцессор  - использую scss и в репозитории он есть. Просто все через Prepros компилируется в css/

3. Не смовсем понял svg sprite но почитаю, хоть верстка и содержит svg для инфографии.  Ок

4. БЭМ  - Не совсем понял мысль с "методологией" Что хотели сказать? Можно еще раз 
6. JS , так как проект не ззавершен, планирую функциона прописать. Просто лежит.

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik. зачем писать  все стили в одном файле, при этом используя препроцессор? - https://github.com/Tryd0g0lik/test_hhr/blob/main/scss/style.scss

Comment: soledar10, по окончанию проекта стили разбиваю на файлы. Разбиваются на шаблоны страниц и характер стиля (нулевой, шаблон, правка, `@media screen`). После  как модули импортирую через `import` в `style.css` чтоб  в `<link>` меньше было .  Разбить ПОБЛОЧНО (header, main, footer) ?

Comment: 4. например, ```class``` ```header_data``` - исходя из методологии ```bem``` это модификатор, а где ```class``` ```header``` для блока?

Comment: @Tryd0g0lik - это необходимо делать при старте проекта

Comment: soledar10, под блоком сам `header` ? Ok спасибо.

Comment: просто представьте себе, что это не ваш код, а чей-то чужой. И вам надо а) максимально быстро в нем разобраться, б) изменить что-то, взбредшее в голову заказчику, нанеся минимальный ущерб всему остальному, в) разделить обязанности по поддержке и развитию проекта на несколько человек, каждый из которых отвечает за свою часть, но при этом не навредив интеграции и г) добавить новый функционал или сменить дизайн в сжатые сроки. 
Получится это у вас?

Comment: у вас почти в каждом модуле повторяются переменные ```$font_size_8: 0.572em;``` (и тд). Лучше их вынести в отдельный модуль, какой-нибудь ```variables.scss```. И подключать где это необходимо

Comment: HaZcker, Ок. Благодарю